# How can I adjust ReSharper's braces layout?

Tags: resharper

I have this code after ReSharper's code cleanup

```
foreach (XElement childElement in
            childSchema.Element(this.xs + "complexType").Element(this.xs + "sequence").Elements(this.xs + "element")
    )
{
    // some code here
}
```

My StyleCop settings don't allow this closing bracket in *foreach* be on separate line, but resharper puts it on separate line when doing silent cleanup. I could not find appropriate option for this in Formatting Style settings.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, Resharper and Stylecop are you using?

Comment: @PiersMyers VS2010, ReSharper 7.1.1 Full Edition, StyleCop 4.3

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the default profile used for cleanup is using StyleCop rules. You could try to follow the steps found in [this](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ConfiguringStyleCopFriendlyCodeCleanUpSettings&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=stylecopforresharper) link. Also, if you go to the Stylecop plugin option there should be a button which you can press if the StyleCop rules are not the same as Resharper is using and it should adjust it for you.

Comment: I don't have this *"StyleCop for ReSharper"* option